# Trying to render div from an object value

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to load a div from an object called matchedLog, but nothing is rendering on the screen. I'm wondering if my code is out of order, I've tried to move around the map piece of the code below the return but then it errors out. I do get the matchedLog value passed down to this function when I console.log, so I think it's the code for this function. Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it.

```
renderMatchedLogs = (matchedLog) => {
        
        return Object.entries(matchedLog).map(([key, value], i) => {
            return (
                <div>
                        {value.dateKey}
                        <br />
                        {value.mealKey}
                        <br />
                        {value.foodSelectedKey}
                        <br />
                        {value.reactionKey}
                        <br />
                </div>
            );
        });
    };
```

When I console.log(matchedLog) this is what I get:

```
{dateKey: "2021-08-17", mealKey: "breakfast", foodSelectedKey: Array(1), reactionKey: "neutral"}
```

The array for the foodSelectedKey is:

```
foodSelectedKey: ["Test"]
```

Comment: Can you please also put `matchedLog` example?

Comment: Yup, added it in!

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 2):

The `Object.entries(matchedLog).map(([key, value], i)` code is unnecessary and is what's causing your problem.

You're creating an array out of the object that looks like this:

```js
// Result of Object.entries(matchedLog)
[
    [
        "dateKey",
        "2021-08-17"
    ],
    [
        "mealKey",
        "breakfast"
    ],
    [
        "foodSelectedKey",
        [
            "test"
        ]
    ],
    [
        "reactionKey",
        "neutral"
    ]
]
```

So when mapping, you can no longer access the values like this: `value.key`, you would just use the `value`.

```js
const obj = {dateKey: "2021-08-17", mealKey: "breakfast", foodSelectedKey: ['test'], reactionKey: "neutral"}

console.log(Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => value))
```

But like I mentioned, this is unnecessary altogether.

You already have the object, so there's no need to turn it into an array and map it.

```js
renderMatchedLogs = (matchedLog) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {matchedLog.dateKey}
      <br />
      {matchedLog.mealKey}
      <br />
      {matchedLog.foodSelectedKey}
      <br />
      {matchedLog.reactionKey}
      <br />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Regarding *I've tried to move around the map piece of the code below the return but then it errors out*:

If `matchedLog` is potentially `undefined` and you're getting an error about accessing a property of undefined, just wrap the whole return in a conditional:

```js
renderMatchedLogs = (matchedLog) => {
  if (matchedLog) {
    return // Your JSX from above
  }
  return null;
}
```

Running example:

```js
const obj = {dateKey: "2021-08-17", mealKey: "breakfast", foodSelectedKey: ['test'], reactionKey: "neutral"}

const Example = () => {
  const renderMatchedLogs = (matchedLog) => {
    return (
      <div>
        {matchedLog.dateKey}
        <br />
        {matchedLog.mealKey}
        <br />
        {matchedLog.foodSelectedKey}
        <br />
        {matchedLog.reactionKey}
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  };
  
  const JSX = renderMatchedLogs(obj)

   return <div>{JSX}</div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I'm still having some trouble having the data rendering on the screen, but I took out the ```Object.entries``` portion of the code

Comment: I just added a running example to my answer. The function works, so the problem with rendering to the screen must be somewhere else in your code. It's impossible to say where.

Comment: I agree, I'll need to keep looking into it. Thank you for your help, I appreciate it!

Comment: No problem. If you isolate it down to another issue feel free to ask another question. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You need to destructure the props.
Assuming that `renderMatchedLogs` is the component, it should be named `RenderMatchedLogs`.
You call it like `<RenderMatchedLogs matchedLogs={...} />`
and then access the passed matchedLogs as a `property` of the props passed to the component.
So the definition should be:

```
const RenderMatchedLogs = (props) => {
  return Object.entries(props.matchedLog).map(([key, value], i) => {
    return (
      <div>
        {value.dateKey}
        <br />
        {value.mealKey}
        <br />
        {value.foodSelectedKey}
        <br />
        {value.reactionKey}
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  });
}
```

or

```
const RenderMatchedLogs = ({ matchedLog }) => { // destructured props
  return Object.entries(matchedLog).map(([key, value], i) => {
    return (
      <div>
        {value.dateKey}
        <br />
        {value.mealKey}
        <br />
        {value.foodSelectedKey}
        <br />
        {value.reactionKey}
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I made a mistake - I didn't mean to say that it was a prop. It's just an object that was received from a different function